# Micromamba inside Docker container

Tags: docker, micromamba

I have a base Docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 \
    && wget -qO-  https://micromamba.snakepit.net/api/micromamba/linux-64/latest | tar -xvj bin/micromamba \
    && touch /root/.bashrc \
    && ./bin/micromamba shell init -s bash -p /opt/conda  \
    && cp /root/.bashrc /opt/conda/bashrc \
    && apt-get clean autoremove --yes \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}

SHELL ["bash", "-l" ,"-c"]
```

and derive from it another one:

```
ARG BASE
FROM $BASE

RUN source /opt/conda/bashrc && micromamba activate \
    && micromamba create --file environment.yaml -p /env
```

While building the second image I get the following error: `micromamba: command not found` for the RUN section.

1. If I run 1st base image manually I can launch micromamba, it is running correctly
2. I can run temporary image which were created for 2nd image building, micromamba is available via CLI, running correctly.
3. If I inherit from debian:buster, or alpine, for example, it is building perfectly.

What a problem with the Ubuntu? Why it cannot see `micromamba` during 2nd Docker image building?

PS using scaffold for building, so it can understand correctly, where is `$BASE` and what is it.

Comment: There is a ready-made [docker image with mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ubuntu:21.04 image comes with a `/root/.bashrc` file that begins with:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

When the second Dockerfile executes `RUN source /opt/conda/bashrc`, PS1 is not set and thus the remainder of the bashrc file does not execute. The remainder of the bashrc file is where `micromamba` initialization occurs, including the setup of the `micromamba` bash function that is used to activate a micromamba environment.

The debian:buster image has a smaller `/root/.bashrc` that does not have a line similar to `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` and therefore the `micromamba` function gets loaded.

The alpine image does not come with a `/root/.bashrc` so it also does not contain the code to exit the file early.

If you want to use the ubuntu:21.04 image, you could modify you first Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 \
    && wget -qO-  https://micromamba.snakepit.net/api/micromamba/linux-64/latest | tar -xvj bin/micromamba \
    && touch /root/.bashrc \
    && ./bin/micromamba shell init -s bash -p /opt/conda  \
    && grep -v '[ -z "\$PS1" ] && return' /root/.bashrc  > /opt/conda/bashrc   # this line has been modified \
    && apt-get clean autoremove --yes \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}

SHELL ["bash", "-l" ,"-c"]
```

This will strip out the one line that causes the early termination.

Alternatively, you could make use of the existing [mambaorg/micromamba](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/mambaorg/micromamba) docker image. The `mambaorg/micromamba:latest` is based on debian:slim, but `mambaorg/micromamba:jammy` will get you a ubuntu-based image (disclosure: I maintain this image).

Comment: I'm having trouble initializing micromamba in my dockerfile so when i activate my docker container it's already initialized.